# Can I access Turtlebot data from different network?

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am working with Turtlebot3 Burger for my project. The idea is to make the robot do surveillance with camera in my lab in university.

However, i want to access the image data from turtlebot camera with my computer in my home,  how can I do it?
What i know i can only do it with computer the same network as turtlebot, but it's gonna be more interesting if i can really do the IoT stuff

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/297667/can-i-access-turtlebot-data-from-different-network?/) by [hansenmaster](https://answers.ros.org/users/36512/hansenmaster/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2018-07-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Well you can definitely do it. You can either set up a streaming server on the ROS network that will make the video accessible the outside world. Or if you want to connect to the ROS network from the outside you will have to set up a VPN connection and use the master/slave connection to do whatever you want with the topics. With the VPN you would of have to set up the [master/slave](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/MultipleMachines) connection to access the remote ROS master.

---

Originally posted by [Reamees](https://answers.ros.org/users/36207/reamees/) with karma: 591 on 2018-07-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1